# Is this correct? “It sounds fun, isn’t it?”

Tags: grammar

Do you say, “It sounds fun, isn’t it?” Shoud we say, “It sounds fun, doesn’t it?”

Comment: The second. The first is a very common error that instantly marks a person as a non-native speaker.

Comment: This is a mistake often made by Japanese speakers. Yes, it is wrong. [should]

Comment: Please edit to tell more about why you thought "isn't" would work here. Voting to close in the meantime as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

[1] It sounds fun.

[2] *It sounds fun, isn’t it?

[3] It sounds fun, doesn’t it?

[1] is the basic clause with "it" as subject and "sounds" as verb.

The 'rule' is that if the anchor verb is an auxiliary, select the same verb, otherwise select the appropriate form of "do".

The verb in [1] is not an auxiliary; it's the lexical verb "sounds", so the correct verb in the tag is "doesn't", as in [3].